# How to set all related entities variable to the same value after one of them get from range?

Tags: optaplanner

Is there any way to make the variable's initial assignment, the same variable of other entities is not obtained from the range, but directly make this value?

For example, there are five teachers who teach five classes. If one of the teachers teaches class#1, then this teacher will always teach class#1 and not change.

I don't want to use hard constraint because there are useless move

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Lecture {
    @Pinned
    private boolean pinned; // true for the pinned lectures
    ...

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["classRange"])
    Klass klass // 

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["teacherRange"])
    Teacher teacher

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["periodRange"])
    Period period

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["roomRange"])
    Room room
}



@PlanningSolution
class CourseSchedule extends AbstractPersistable {
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    List<Lecture> lectureList = Lists.newArrayList()
}


// ----- that's what i want 

// if klass was set klass#1 and teacher was set teacher#2
// all the lecture with klass#1 's teacher set to teacher#2 too  
lectureList.each {
    Lecture l ->
    if(l.klass == klass#1) {
        l.teacher = teacher#2
    }

    // and l.teacher and l.klass are immutable before solution reset 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Pinned` on a boolean field on the @PlanningEntity for this, see docs for more info.

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Lecture {
    @Pinned
    private boolean pinned; // true for the pinned lectures
    ...
}
```

If that's not powerful enough, look at it's bigger brother `@PlanningEntity(immovableEntityFilter = ...)`, see docs too.

Comment: i update my post and i wish you could enlighten me on

Comment: i just need class(or klass) and teacher not change, but period and room are mutable, if i use immovableEntityFilter implements SelectionFilter<CourseSchedule, Lecture>, i don't know which variable change and i need variable name, then i can decide the entity are change or not